# Google Container Registry images lifecycle

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I would like to know if there is a way to setup an objects lifecycle in GCP Container Registry?

I would like to keep the last `n` versions of an image, automatically deleting the older ones as new ones are pushed online.

I can't work directly on the Cloud Storage bucket because, having multiple images saved, the storage objects are not recognizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunaltely, there is no concept pf managed lifecycle management of images managed in GCR just like there is in AWS which allows creating policies to manage images in the registry.

You have to plan this yourself i.e. a script which emulates the following behavior and runs periodically.

```
gcloud container images delete -q --force-delete-tags "${IMAGE}@${digest}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Seth Vargo, a Google Cloud developer advocate has release [GCRCleaner](https://github.com/sethvargo/gcr-cleaner).

Follow the instruction for setting up a scheduler and a Cloud Run for cleaning the GCR.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at this time there’s no feature able to do such in GCR, however there’s already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/113559510) created. You can follow on it and write comments.

Also check [this](https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/7ce6d741bd5baa194a3fac6b1fec8bb7) example, where image deletion was implemented in specific time.